# How to access data from another model using same foreign key?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want get college data using general_info foreign key. without making nested serializer of college_set in GeneralInfo serializer. Is there any alternative in django rest framework or is not possible? I have tried above below line of code but its not working. is there any other way?

```
college = serializers.CharField(source='general_info.college_set', read_only=True)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class GeneralInfo(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Student(models.Model):
    general_info = models.ForeignKey(to=GeneralInfo, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    marks = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class College(models.Model):
    general_info = models.OneToOneField(to=GeneralInfo, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='users/')
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='general_info.first_name', read_only=True)
    college = serializers.CharField(source='general_info.college_set', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name', 'college')
```

Comment: `OneToOneField` may be you need `source='general_info.college`?

Comment: But its not returning me the full path my images are in media folder but it just returning me /users/myimage.jpeg . path that i need media/users/myimage.jpeg

Comment: `College` model doesn't even contain `ImageField` or `FileField`, why would it return media paths?

Comment: @Gasanov sorry my mistake there is an `ImageField`  too.

Comment: @BearBrown Thank you for help. but how can I return the full path? `source='general_info.college.picture'`

Comment: may be `serializers.ImageField(source='general_info.college.picture')`?